# Are URL's automatically decoded if there is any html entities in the URL?

Tags: php, url, uri

**The scenario**:- I am redirecting the user to the previous page after the successful login. ***login.php*** has a form which takes username and password and POSTs to the *login_check.php*. *login_check.php* checks for authentication of the user and if passed it redirects the user to the default page unless the user has a choice(i.e: if he visited to some other page,say ***people's.php*** and that people's.php finds that he is not logged in and redirects him to login page so that he can get back after successful login). I am also storing the visited URL in a hidden field in the form in ***login.php*** :-

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="location" value="';
 if(isset($_GET['location']))
 {
  echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['location']);
 }
echo '"/>';
```

In **login_check.php**, after authentication check I check whether there is a user choice otherwise redirects him to default page:-

```
//REDIRECT USER TO PREVIOUS PAGE IF ANY
if(isset($_POST['location']))
{
   header("location:".$_POST['location']);
   exit;
}
```

**My question**:- If I write the URI *people's.php* in the browser it prompts me to log in accordingly and redirects me after login.If I try something like ***people&lsquo;s.php*** I get page not found message.(As Encoded URL using htmlspecialchars() is stored in the hidden field as shown in the code above). So,where does the decoding of the URL take place and why does it not work the other way(i.e:people&lsquo;s.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write an HTML entity in an HTML document (and not inside an element with intrinsic CDATA, like `<script>`), then the entity will be decoded as the HTML is parsed and the DOM is generated.

This is what happens in your `<input value=...` example.

When the browser constructs the URL from the inputs in the form when the form is submitted, the entities have already been decoded.

---

When you put an HTML entity in an HTTP header (such as `location`, then it will not be decoded by the browser. HTTP headers are not HTML documents so will not be parsed as HTML.

In your example, the entity was already decoded by the browser before being sent to the server to populate `$_POST`.

---

When you put an HTML entity in the browser's address bar, then it will not be decoded by the browser. URLs are not HTML documents so will not be parsed as HTML.

Answer (score -1):

my opinion is, you should not name files with characters that needs to be encoded.

In file login_check.php you can use this:

```
header("location:".htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['location']));
```

to decode `&lsquo;` back to ‘